# Bash: Invalidated commands

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, terminal

I've incurred a worrisome issue with my bash shell. I was editing my `bash_profile` and accidentally exported an incomplete command (`export PATH=/usr/local/bin`). After I had reloaded my terminal, nearly all of my bash commands fail to work properly. When I try to run any one of them, the errors state: `command not found`.

How do I fix this? Is there an alternate way to open or find my `bash_profile`?

I would appreciate any immediate input I can get on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can try and setting to for example `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`. This will contain more paths so you can work better. Try to check logs to see what was the previous path.

Comment: Thank you so much. I edited the bash profile file and fixed it. Is there anything else I should do/check to set my shell back to the way it was?

Comment: Also, add your comment as the answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: user3181113: You should use @fedorqui to address him/her, that way he/she'll be notified (no need for this time, this comment is doing it)

Comment: Keep copies of your `.bash_profile` and similar files in a source control system so you can recover more easily from mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* execute commands *if* you can give the directory name. Almost all the basic Unix commands are under the `/bin` or `/usr/bin` directory. For example, `/bin/mv`.

Fortunately, builtin commands are still recognizable.

Move your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` file out of the way for now, and see what the system default is.

You can manually edit your `PATH` on the command line to:

```
$ PATH="/bin:/usr/bin"
$ cd
$ mv .bash_profile .bash_profile.bak
$ mv .bashrc .bashrc.bak
$ mv .profile .profile.bak
$ mv .bash_login .bash_login.bak
```

***NOTE***: *Some of these mv command may fail simply because that particular file may not exist.*

which will give you access to most of the basic Unix commands. Or you can specify the commands with their full directory names:

```
$ PATH="/bin:/usr/bin"
$ cd
$ /bin/mv .bash_profile .bash_profile.bak
$ /bin/mv .bashrc .bashrc.bak
$ /bin/mv .profile .profile.bak
$ /bin/mv .bash_login .bash_login.bak
```

Now, log in again and see what your default `$PATH` is set to. This is set by the `/etc/profile`. You might find that's just fine, and remove setting `PATH` in your startup script.

The standard for `PATH` is something like this:

- `/usr/share/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` - These contain non-standard Unix/Linux commands. For example, if you install Maven on your system, the `mvn` command will usually be located in one of these directories (maybe as a symbolic link). This directory is a place where commands not found in the `/bin` and `/usr/bin` directory are stored. This directory is first, so you can replace the version which came with your system with more recent versions. For example, I might have VIM 6.4 installed, but I want to use version 7.3 instead.
- `/bin:/usr/bin` - The standard directories where 99% of the Unix commands live.
- `$HOME/bin` - These are executables you wrote -- either scripts or binaries. This is at the end of the PATH list because it makes sure that you don't accidentally execute the wrong version of the command. Imagine if some joker wrote a shell script called `cp` that executed `/bin/rm` instead and placed it in your `$HOME/bin` directory.

Other directories you'll see may include `/sbin/` and `/usr/sbin` which are administrator commands (`ping` and `ifconfig` are sometimes in one of these directories.) `/opt/bin/X11` (or wherever the X11 binaries are stored). Sometimes other commands will futz around with your PATH, for example [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl).

Comment: This is an excellent answer and explanation. I chose it because it provides a long-term fix while being comprehensive enough to assist others in understanding and fixing near-similar situations. As mklement0 states, ferdorqui's answer certainly works quickly, while his/her answer provides a longer-term, alternate route. I appreciate all of the assistance.

Comment: Very comprehensive! +1 for providing such a good answer that I favorited to read quietly. I am considering deleting mine, as it was just a comment converted into answer.

Answer (score 1):

[@fedorqui's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24260487/bash-invalidated-commands/24270015#comment37477197_24260487) provides a quick fix.

The OP could also have used the following to quickly get to a shell with default values for `$PATH`:

To **create a `bash` shell with a pristine default environment**:

- without running profile/initialization scripts
- without inheriting any environment variables from the current shell

run:

```
 /usr/bin/env -i bash --norc
```

Note:

- Due to use of `env`'s `-i` option, many environment variables that are normally set will NOT be set in the resulting shell , such as `USER`, `HOME` and `LANG`.

  - Similarly, the `$PATH` value you'll get is presumably one hard-coded into `bash` itself, but it should provide access to at least the standard utilities.
- `--norc` suppresses loading of `~/.bashrc`, which normally happens by default for *interactive non-login* bash shells (`bash` also supports the `--noprofile` option to suppress loading of `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile`, but it doesn't apply here, since the shell created is a *non-login* shell).
- If `env` is in the current shell's `$PATH`, `env -i bash --norc` will do.
- `env` is in `/usr/bin/` on at least Linux and on FreeBSD/OSX, probably also on other platforms.